# python: datetime strftime not working properly with file naming

Tags: python

here is my code:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

time = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
f = open(r'C:/folder' + time + '.txt', 'w')
f.write("Something")
f.close()
```

But output is e.g. **2022-06-13-00-00-00** at **14:19:53**.
Could you, please, hint me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this -

```
 from datetime import datetime
 time_curr = datetime.now()
 print(time_curr)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using date.today(), which [returns today's date without any time set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-date).
You want to use [datetime.now()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-date), which returns the date along with the time.

So, you should change your code to the following.

```
from datetime import datetime

time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
f = open(r'C:/folder' + time + '.txt', 'w')
f.write("Something")
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped, sorry for kind of stupid question :)

Comment: @nikita1221 No problem, glad to help. I get that it might be hard to miss, as you'd suspect the formatting rules first.